# Ansible fatal error while trying to print the state of firewalld

Tags: ansible, firewalld

Here, i am trying to print the status of the firewall-cmd --state command , but a fatal error is being thrown.

```
 name: Check firewall status
        hosts: st

        tasks:
        - name: Check status of firewall
          command: firewall-cmd --state
          register: status

        - name: Print version
          debug:
             msg: "Status = {{ status.stdout }}"
```

State is "not running" in the remote host. But am not getting the result.

I get the following output

```
fatal: [borexample.com]: FAILED! => {"changed": true, "cmd": ["firewall-cmd", "--state"], "delta": "0:00:00.189023", "end": "2018-09-16 11:40:17.319482", "msg": "non-zero return code", "rc": 252, "start": "2018-09-16 11:40:17.130459", "stderr": "", "stderr_lines": [], "stdout": "\u001b[91mnot running\u001b[00m", "stdout_lines": ["\u001b[91mnot running\u001b[00m"]}
```

How should i modify the code so that i get only the state ?

Comment: the task "Check status of firewall" does not return a return code egal to 0 so it throws an error. If you want to ignore the status you can add `ignore_errors: true` aligned with `register`.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer using `failed_when:` to control your output rc. More info at [Ansible Documentation](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.6/user_guide/playbooks_error_handling.html). But you can also use `ìgnore_errors: true`

Check error codes in the [Firewall-cmd Documentation](https://firewalld.org/documentation/man-pages/firewall-cmd.html) to see which codes adding to your playbook.

In your scenario could be good doing:

```
  - name: Check status of firewall
    command: firewall-cmd --state
    register: status
    failed_when:
      - status.rc != 0 
      - status.rc != 252
```

Even you can go further and use `failed_when: false` to avoid the command failing.

Comment: when i tried to print using debug: msg:{{status.stdout}}, not getting any output.  Firewalld is not running, so the status should be 252. If i give {{status.stderr}} then it gets printed though.

Comment: "msg": "\u001b[91mnot running\u001b[00m  -  status.stderr gives this. but status.stdout doesnt print anything

Comment: What do you want to do after that? Are you going to manage something else with the stdout? Please add an example to help. BTW: Sorry for the delay in my answer I was on holidays

Answer (score 0):

The ignore_errors suggested by Baptiste Mille-Mathias would allow you to continue, but then you would like to "debug" {{ status.stderr }}, as in that ase stdout would be empty.

Comment: But what if i have to make a comparison based on the return value. From status.stderr, how can that be done